# Getting date using day of the week

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have problem in finding the date using day of the week.

For example : i have past date lets say,

```
Date date= Convert.TodateTime("01/08/2013");
```

08th Jan 2013 th Day of the week is Tuesday.

Now i want current week's tuesday's date. How i can do it.

Note : The past date is dynamic. It will change in every loop.

Comment: Just a thought: if you already are on the correct day, you can add weeks to the date, while staying on the same day. So add weeks to the date until you arrive at the current week.

Comment: yes. Is there any inbuilt method to do that/

Comment: `DateTime.AddDays(7)` is an option to add a single week. You can multiply the number of weeks by 7 and add it. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Hey john, for that i have to loop through it. Is there any shortcut way?

Comment: Steve's answer below is probably the shortest way to get this result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the enumeration [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

> The DayOfWeek enumeration represents the day of the week in calendars
>   that have seven days per week. The value of the constants in this
>   enumeration ranges from DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If
>   cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

We can use the conversion to integer to calculate the difference from the current date of the same week day

```
DateTime dtOld = new DateTime(2013,1,8);
int num = (int)dtOld.DayOfWeek;
int num2 = (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
DateTime result = DateTime.Today.AddDays(num - num2);
```

This also seems appropriate to create an extension method

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime EquivalentWeekDay(this DateTime dtOld)
    {
        int num = (int)dtOld.DayOfWeek;
        int num2 = (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        return DateTime.Today.AddDays(num - num2);
    }
}
```

and now you could call it with

```
DateTime weekDay = Convert.ToDateTime("01/08/2013").EquivalentWeekDay();
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be a bit late to the party, but my solution is very similar:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Tuesday));
```

This will get the Tuesday of the current week, where finding Tuesday is the primary goal (I may have misunderstood the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this....

```
public static void Main()
{ 
    //current date  
    DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6);

    //you can use it custom date  
    var cmYear = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

    //here 2 is the day value of the week in a date
    var customDateWeek = cmYear.AddDays(-2); 
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
    Console.WriteLine(cmYear);
    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + customDateWeek);
    Console.WriteLine();  
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```