# How to enter a date and get back the day of the week

Tags: c#, datetime

My program uses `Console.ReadLine()` to take the year, month and day as integers, then it should print the day of the week for that date.

For example I enter today's date, Year: 2018, Month: 05, Day: 03.

And the program prints to the screen: Thursday

So far I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the day...");
int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the month...");
int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the year...");
int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//The part of the code I need help with
string day_of_week = "";

Console.WriteLine(day_of_week);
```

Comment: something like `console.log(new DateTime(year, month, day).DayOfWeek);`

Comment: If you just need the string representation of the day of the week, just use `myDate.ToString("ddd")` (three-letter day name) or `myDate.ToString("dddd")` (full name).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting date using day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875443/getting-date-using-day-of-the-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create `DateTime` and check the `DayOfWeek`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);
```

[MSDN Link for DateTime structure.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew how to make a datetime like this: DateTime.now but didn't know how to edit that day.